# Proving C1-smoothness of a function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Im having trouble understanding this question:

Prove that the equation $e^{z-1}+2zy+x-3y^{3}=0$ defines z as a $C^{1}$-smooth function of x and y in a neighbourhood of the point $P=(0,1,1)$. Determine the partial derivatives $z'_{x}(0,1)$ and $z'_{y}(0,1)$.

To be honest I have no clue on how you solve these kind of problems. I have looked at a similar exercise that had the solution available.

So what I did was to use the same concept as in that solution:

(i) Plugging in P in the equation we have $R.H.S=0=L.HS$

(ii) Construct $F(x,y,z)=e^{z-1}+2zy+x-3y^{3}$, $\quad$ $F_{z}=e^{z-2} + 2y$ 
$\quad$ and $F_{z}(0,1,1)=\frac{1}{e}+2 \neq 0 $

Hence by the implicit function theorem there exists a $C^{1}$ function in a neighbourhood of $P$ such that $e^{z(x,y)-1}+2z(x,y)y+x-3y^{3}=0$ holds.

But I have no clue on how to continue or computing $z'_{x}(0,1)$ and $z'_{y}(0,1)$. Could someone help me out? and maybe with the intuition on these kind of exercises? Would appreciate..

Answer (score 0):

If you do implicit differentiation of the equality $$
e^{z(x,y)-1}+2z(x,y)y+x-3y^{3}=0
$$
w.r.t. $x$ in a neighbourhood of $(0,1)$, you'll obtain
$$
e^{z(x,y)-1}z_x'(x,y)+2z_x'(x,y)y+1=0.
$$
Then set $(x,y)=(0,1)$
$$
(e^0+2)z_x'(0,1)+1=0\ \Rightarrow\ z_x'(0,1)=-\frac{1}{3}.
$$
Similarly for $z_y'(0,1)$.

Comment: After we set $(x,y)=(0,1)$ how do we know that $e^{z(0,1)-1}=e^{0}$ ?

Comment: @fejz1234 You know the point $P=(0,1,1)$, so $z(0,1)=1$. It also follows from the original equation for $(x,y)=(0,1)$.